# Verbs that go with a specific noun -- name for this?

Tags: word-usage

The verb for lying is "told","I told a lie." Occasionally I will hear, "I said a lie."
The latter usage really is cringey to me although perhaps "said" is a common usage in some areas.

Is "said" actually wrong? What do you call verbs that seem to go with specific nouns?

Comment: They can be used interchangeably (It's matter of personal preference).

Comment: @Sam: I do not think I have ever heard a native speak say, "I said a lie." -- sounds extremely strange to my native speaker ears.

Comment: @Sam, that is quite untrue. See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=told+a+lie%2C+said+a+lie&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - and if you look at the examples of _said a lie_, many of them are false positives ('He/she said' followed by a speech beginning with 'A lie...')

Comment: I don't know if there's a term more specific than [set phrase or phraseme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phraseme). You can do other things with lies such as "come out with a lie" but "tell a lie" is definitely the most common way of expressing it.

Comment: Prolly go with Stuart's set phrase or phraseme yet while 'I told a lie' is almost universal, what's wrong with 'I gave him/spoke/used/voiced…' or, though it's a step further away, 'I threw a lie in her face'?

Can you see other, less flexible verbs?

(PS: As I typed 'a step further away' the TV sang 'I'm moving farther away… Yazoo, Only You, 1982)